# github actions for running test with testcontainers and gradle

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, github-actions, testcontainers

I'm new to github actions (comming from gitlab-ci) I'm trying to run a integration test with testcontainers in the pipeline and I'm stucked. Here is my current definition.

```
name: Run Gradle
on: push
jobs:
  gradle:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ ubuntu-18.04  ]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - uses: eskatos/gradle-command-action@v1
        with:
          build-root-directory: backend
          wrapper-directory: backend
          arguments: check assemble
```

**How can I ensure that the docker deamon for testcontainers project is available during my run?**

Answer (score 12):

You can check the installed packages/software for each GitHub Actions Runner as part of the `virtual-environment` [GitHub repository](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments).

For `ubuntu-18.04` you can find the list [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md). Docker and Docker Compose are already installed on the runner and you can use them without any additional configuration for Testcontainers.

I'm using GitHub Actions for a lot of projects that make heavy use of Testcontainers without any problems.

Comment: Updated link nowadays https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-Readme.md, I think

Comment: Further updated URL:

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/tree/main#available-images